# Trying to wrap my head around closures in Dart

Tags: javascript, dart, closures

I am currently learning Google Dart. I am currently confused in trying to understand what is going on in this piece of code taken out from the dart docs:

```
Function makeAdder(num addBy) {
  return (num i) => addBy + i;
}

void main() {
  // Create a function that adds 2.
  var add2 = makeAdder(2);

  // Create a function that adds 4.
  var add4 = makeAdder(4);

  assert(add2(3) == 5);
  assert(add4(3) == 7);
}
```

What I'm finding so hard to understand is the `add2(3)` and `add(3)` part. `makeAdder(2)` and `makeAdder(4)` from what I've gathered assigns the variable `addBy` to 2 and 4 repectively in their own scope. So the variable add2 has 2 assigned to addBy and the variable add4 has 4 assigned to addBy. But I don't quite understand this: when executing the function with the parameters (i.e. `add2(3)` and `add4(3)`) shouldn't the parameters be assigning the variable `addBy` so `addBy` should both be equal to 3 respecitvely of the variables? and How does Dart know to assign i to 3 rather than addBy?

I hope im making sense.

Answer (score 3):

`makeAdder` takes one parameter (`addBy`) and returns a function which also takes one parameter (`i`).

When you call `var add2 = makeAdder(2)`, the argument `2` here is passed to `addBy`, and the function returns a lambda equivalent to:

```
num add2(num i) { 
  return 2 + i;
}
```

Later when you call `add2(3)`, the argument `3` is passed to `i`.

The key is to understand that `makeAdder` returns a function that takes a parameter.

Comment: Ohhkay. I get it now. The block of code made it so much simpler to understand

Comment: But what if I wanted the function to return nothing? For example, `Function makeAdder(num addBy, num addByy) {
  print(addBy.toString() + addByy.toString());
}`. I then write the following: `var add2 = makeAdder(2200,2);

  add2() ;` this doesn't work as I am getting a NoSuchMethod Exception

Comment: If `makeAdder` returns nothing you probably shouldn't assign it to a variable. You get a NoSuchMethod because `add2` is not a function, since you assigned `makeAdder` to it which returned nothing.

Answer (score 0):

makeAdder is returning a function here. The function you return from makeAdder is basically a closer. Once you call makeAdder with an argument, it’s value will persist in addBy param. So when you do a call like makeAdder(2)(3), it will return 5.

In simple javascript, this function will be as below -

```
var makeAdder = function(addBy) {
    return (param) => { 
        return addBy+param;
    }
}
```

inner function is just a simple arrow function. If we call makeAdder as makeAdder(5)(6), it will return 11